# Return Varchar value from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, procedure

I have the following basic stored Procedure which return varchar value

```
create proc myproc
AS
return 'SSS'
```

Now when I call this stored procedure using the following query

```
declare @ret varchAR(max)
 exec sp_executesql N'exec @ret =procc', 
N'@ret varchar(MAX) OUTPUT',@ret = @ret OUTPUT select @ret  as result
```

I get error the following error

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SSS' to data type int.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Stored procedures in MS SQL Sever can only return an Integer.

Did you want to use an output parameter instead?

```
CREATE PROC [myproc]
    @output VARCHAR(3) OUTPUT
AS
    SET @output = 'SSS';
RETURN 0;
```

Which you could call like this,

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(3);
EXEC [myproc] @output OUTPUT;
SELECT @output;
```

Or maybe you'd prefer to return a scalar result set?

```
CREATE PROC [myproc]
AS
    SELECT 'SSS';
RETURN 0;
```

which would return the same by simply executing,

```
EXEC [myproc];
```

Comment: How will I call this sp if it has parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

Since stored procedures in MS SQL Sever can only return an Integer, try selecting the value rather than returning it:

```
create proc myproc AS SELECT 'SSS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have output parameter

```
create proc myproc
(@value varchar(100) output)
AS
select @value='SSS'

GO

declare @ret varchAR(max)
 exec sp_executesql N'exec @ret =procc', 
N'@ret varchar(MAX) OUTPUT',@ret = @ret OUTPUT select @ret  as result
```

Comment: what is `outout`? Essentailly my answer, 2 minutes later, without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value from stored procedure, you have to declare an output parameter for that.

Hope the below code will help you

```
create proc myproc
@outputvalue VARCHAR (16) output
AS
set @outputvalue='SSS'
select @outputvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter procedure GetPrueba(@a int, @b int, @Suma INT OUTPUT, @Resta int OUTPUT) as
begin
select  @Suma=@a+@b, @Resta=@a- @b
end

alter procedure getprueba2 as
begin
declare @s int, @r int
exec getprueba 2,5, @s OUTPUT, @r OUTPUT
select @s,@r
end


getprueba2
```